# WebView2 in PowerShell Winform GUI

Tags: winforms, powershell, scripting, webview2

I have not been able to find any information on this so I'm not sure its entirely possible. I'm currently trying to integrate the WebView2 control into my PowerShell Winform GUI. I can see while debugging my script that the webView2 control is created, but nothing ever loads. I have the WebView2 runtime installed.

This is what I have so far:

```
function Show-test-WebView2Control_psf {

#----------------------------------------------
#region Import the Assemblies
#----------------------------------------------
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadFile('C:\Tests\Assemblies\Debug\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.dll')
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadFile('C:\Tests\Assemblies\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll')
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadFile('C:\Tests\Assemblies\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf.dll')
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
#endregion Import Assemblies

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Objects
#----------------------------------------------
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$buttonRefresh = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$buttonGo = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$textbox1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
[Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2] $webview = New-Object 'Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2'
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState'
#endregion Generated Form Objects

#----------------------------------------------
# User Generated Script
#----------------------------------------------

$form1_Load={
    #TODO: Initialize Form Controls here
    $webview.Source = ([uri]::new($textbox1.Text))
    $webview.Visible = $true
}

$webview_Ready = {
    $webview.NavigateToString("https://www.google.com")
}


$webview_CoreWebView2Ready={
    $webview.Source = [System.Uri]$textbox1.Text
}

$buttonGo_Click={
    #TODO: Place custom script here
    $webview.Source = [System.Uri] $textbox1.Text;
}

$webview_SourceChanged={
    $form1.Text = $webview.Source.AbsoluteUri;
}

# --End User Generated Script--
#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Events
#----------------------------------------------

$Form_StateCorrection_Load=
{
    #Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

$Form_Cleanup_FormClosed=
{
    #Remove all event handlers from the controls
    try
    {
        $buttonGo.remove_Click($buttonGo_Click)
        $webview.remove_CoreWebView2Ready($webview_CoreWebView2Ready)
        $webview.remove_SourceChanged($webview_SourceChanged)
        $form1.remove_Load($form1_Load)
        $form1.remove_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
        $form1.remove_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
    }
    catch { Out-Null <# Prevent PSScriptAnalyzer warning #> }
}
#endregion Generated Events

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
#----------------------------------------------
$form1.SuspendLayout()
#
# form1
#
$form1.Controls.Add($buttonRefresh)
$form1.Controls.Add($buttonGo)
$form1.Controls.Add($textbox1)
$form1.Controls.Add($webview)
$form1.AutoScaleDimensions = New-Object System.Drawing.SizeF(6, 13)
$form1.AutoScaleMode = 'Font'
$form1.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(619, 413)
$form1.Name = 'form1'
$form1.Text = 'Form'
$form1.add_Load($form1_Load)
#
# buttonRefresh
#
$buttonRefresh.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(13, 13)
$buttonRefresh.Name = 'buttonRefresh'
$buttonRefresh.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$buttonRefresh.TabIndex = 3
$buttonRefresh.Text = 'Refresh'
$buttonRefresh.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# buttonGo
#
$buttonGo.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(538, 9)
$buttonGo.Name = 'buttonGo'
$buttonGo.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$buttonGo.TabIndex = 2
$buttonGo.Text = 'Go'
$buttonGo.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$buttonGo.add_Click($buttonGo_Click)
#
# textbox1
#
$textbox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(96, 13)
$textbox1.Name = 'textbox1'
$textbox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(435, 20)
$textbox1.TabIndex = 1
$textbox1.Text = 'https://www.bing.com'
#
# webview
#
$webview.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0, 49)
$webview.Name = 'webview'
$webview.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(619, 364)
$webview.TabIndex = 0
$webview.ZoomFactor = 1
$webview.add_SourceChanged($webview_SourceChanged)

$form1.ResumeLayout()
#endregion Generated Form Code

#----------------------------------------------

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
#Clean up the control events
$form1.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
#Show the Form
    return $form1.ShowDialog()

} #End Function

    #Call the form
    Show-test-WebView2Control_psf | Out-Null
```

Is there a way to do this? If so, can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Q: Why try to manually build an entire WinForms app, method-by-method, control-by-control, in PS?  Why not just write a nice, simple WinForms app using MSVS? And then call the app from PS, if you need to?

Comment: I have used FoxDeploy's guide to making a GUI in PowerShell, and recommend it whenever I see others trying to do the same. Check it out here: https://foxdeploy.com/series/learning-gui-toolmaking-series

Comment: Youtube UX/UI design videos is where you should be looking. [UX/UI Best Practice](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ux%2Fui+best+practice)  [UX/UI WinForm WPF](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ux%2Fui+winform+wpf) [UX/UI WinForm WPF PowerShell](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ux%2Fui+winform+wpf+powershell). This `Show-test-WebView2Control_psf` is not proper naming for PowerShell functions, scripts, etc. PowerShell uses a Verb-Noun construct as a best/common/accepted implementation practice.

Comment: Again, Youtube --- [winform webview2](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=winform+webview2) and [wpf webview2](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=wpf+webview2)  [winform webview2 powershell](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=winform+webview2+powershell) [wpf webview2 powershell](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=wpf+webview2+powershell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying out your code on my own I had to resolve two issues:

- From the webview2 nuget package (for reference I used the [WebView2 nuget 1.0.781-prerelease package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2/1.0.781-prerelease)) I copied the winforms and core DLL from the net45 folder and I copied the x64 webview2loader.dll all into the wv2 folder. You need to ensure the webview2loader.dll of the appropriate CPU architecture is copied next to the core dll.
- The default WebView2 user data folder is in the folder containing the host executable. In this case the host executable is powershell and the containing folder isn't writable by normal processes. So you need to change the user data folder which you can do via the [CoreWebView2CreationProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.corewebview2creationproperties) UserDataFolder property before the WebView2 is initialized.

I have the modified code below. Additional work is required to resize and close the WebView2 and resolve other issues.

```
function Show-test-WebView2Control_psf {

#----------------------------------------------
#region Import the Assemblies
#----------------------------------------------
# I've put the following files in `C:\users\davris\tmp\wv2`
#     Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll
#     Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.dll
#     WebView2Loader.dll
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadFile('C:\users\davris\tmp\wv2\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.dll')
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadFile('C:\users\davris\tmp\wv2\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll')
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a')
[void][reflection.assembly]::Load('System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089')
#endregion Import Assemblies

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Objects
#----------------------------------------------
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$buttonRefresh = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$buttonGo = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'
$textbox1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'
[Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2] $webview = New-Object 'Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2'
$webview.CreationProperties = New-Object 'Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.CoreWebView2CreationProperties'
$webview.CreationProperties.UserDataFolder = "C:\users\davris\tmp\wv2\data";
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState'
#endregion Generated Form Objects

#----------------------------------------------
# User Generated Script
#----------------------------------------------

$form1_Load={
    #TODO: Initialize Form Controls here
    $webview.Source = ([uri]::new($textbox1.Text))
    $webview.Visible = $true
}

$buttonGo_Click={
    #TODO: Place custom script here
    $webview.Source = [System.Uri] $textbox1.Text;
}

$webview_SourceChanged={
    $form1.Text = $webview.Source.AbsoluteUri;
}

# --End User Generated Script--
#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Events
#----------------------------------------------

$Form_StateCorrection_Load=
{
    #Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

$Form_Cleanup_FormClosed=
{
    #Remove all event handlers from the controls
    try
    {
        $buttonGo.remove_Click($buttonGo_Click)
        $webview.remove_SourceChanged($webview_SourceChanged)
        $form1.remove_Load($form1_Load)
        $form1.remove_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
        $form1.remove_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
    }
    catch { Out-Null <# Prevent PSScriptAnalyzer warning #> }
}
#endregion Generated Events

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
#----------------------------------------------
$form1.SuspendLayout()
#
# form1
#
$form1.Controls.Add($buttonRefresh)
$form1.Controls.Add($buttonGo)
$form1.Controls.Add($textbox1)
$form1.Controls.Add($webview)
$form1.AutoScaleDimensions = New-Object System.Drawing.SizeF(6, 13)
$form1.AutoScaleMode = 'Font'
$form1.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(619, 413)
$form1.Name = 'form1'
$form1.Text = 'Form'
$form1.add_Load($form1_Load)
#
# buttonRefresh
#
$buttonRefresh.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(13, 13)
$buttonRefresh.Name = 'buttonRefresh'
$buttonRefresh.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$buttonRefresh.TabIndex = 3
$buttonRefresh.Text = 'Refresh'
$buttonRefresh.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
#
# buttonGo
#
$buttonGo.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(538, 9)
$buttonGo.Name = 'buttonGo'
$buttonGo.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
$buttonGo.TabIndex = 2
$buttonGo.Text = 'Go'
$buttonGo.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$buttonGo.add_Click($buttonGo_Click)
#
# textbox1
#
$textbox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(96, 13)
$textbox1.Name = 'textbox1'
$textbox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(435, 20)
$textbox1.TabIndex = 1
$textbox1.Text = 'https://www.bing.com'
#
# webview
#
$webview.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0, 49)
$webview.Name = 'webview'
$webview.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(619, 364)
$webview.TabIndex = 0
$webview.ZoomFactor = 1
$webview.add_SourceChanged($webview_SourceChanged)

$form1.ResumeLayout()
#endregion Generated Form Code

#----------------------------------------------

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
#Clean up the control events
$form1.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
#Show the Form
    return $form1.ShowDialog()

} #End Function

    #Call the form
    Show-test-WebView2Control_psf | Out-Null
```